# Adding two of the same foreighn keys to a single model as two different fields in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am building the database structure for a project using sequelize. I am created the friends table for the project. Is it possible to set a user foreign key to two different fields (friender, friended) in the friend database table using sequelize. I know that I can create a foreign key using `Friend.hasOne(User) User.hasMany(Friend)` but that just assigns one field as a foreign key. I want to have two foreign keys that are the same model as two different fields.

This is what I have so far for my sequelize database model (Friend):

```
const seq = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../index');

const Friend = database.define(
  "friend",
  {
    id:{
      type:seq.INTEGER,
      primaryKey:true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    favorite:{
      type:seq.STRING,
      null:true,
      validate:{
        isUrl: true,
      }
    },
  },{
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  },
  database.sync()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Profile table is synced")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("caught error with Profile: " + error)
    })
);

Friend.hasOne(User)
User.hasMany(Friends)
```

I want `Friend.friender` to be a foreign key to `User` 
I want `Friend.friended` to also be a foriegn key to `User`

Not sure how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use Many to Many relation between Friend and User models, and allow to select type of relation between them by custom relation model?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: well i want to do it in node.js not django.... i had initially build the database in django but I am transferring it to node.js

Answer (score 0):

It's called many to many relation through pivot table.

Add few fields to model and define many to many relation through it:

```
const seq = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../index');

const Friend = database.define(
  "friends",
  {
    id:{
      type:seq.INTEGER,
      primaryKey:true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    userId: {
      type: seq.INTEGER,
    },
    friendUserId: {
      type: seq.INTEGER,
    },
    favorite:{
      type:seq.STRING,
      null:true,
      validate:{
        isUrl: true,
      }
    },
  },{
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  }
);

User.hasMany(
  User, 
  {
    as: 'friends',
    through: Friend, 
    foreignKey: 'friendUserId'
  }
);
```