# My Seq foreign key is not being set in my postgres table: Profie - User

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postgres database that I am building using sequelize. I have a user object and a profile object. I want there to be a foreignkey that links the user with the foreign key that i am setting within the profile table.

Code:

```
const seq = require('sequelize');
const { postgres } = require('../../index');
const { user } = require('./user');
// const { picture, backgroundImage } = require('./ProfileAttachments');

const profile = postgres.define(
  "profile",
  {
    id: {
      type: seq.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    bio: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      null: true
    },
    facebook: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      null: true,
      validate: {
        isUrl:  true,
      }
    },
    twitter: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      null: true,
      validate: {
        isUrl:  true,
      }
    },
    website: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      null: true,
      validate: {
        isUrl:  true,
      }
    },
  },{
    createdAt:  seq.DATE,
    updatedAt:  seq.DATE,
  },
  postgres.sync()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Profile table is synced")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("caught error with Profile:  " + error)
    })
);

// picture.addTo(profile);
// backgroundImage.addTo(profile);

user.hasOne(profile)

module.exports.profile = profile
```

this is my table:

```
splitter=# \d+ profiles;
 id       | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('profiles_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 bio      | character varying(255)   |           |          |                                      | extended |              | 
 facebook | character varying(255)   |           |          |                                      | extended |              | 
 twitter  | character varying(255)   |           |          |                                      | extended |              | 
 website  | character varying(255)   |           |          |                                      | extended |              | 
 DATE     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              | 

splitter=#
```

I tried to do both `user.hasOne(profile)` an `profile.hasOne(user)`.

i did have the foreign key appear the first time i synced the database. I changed something and then it went away and I am not sure how that happened. can someone help. I am pretty sure it is something small that i cant see anymore.

Comment: try this: `user.hasOne(profile)`, `profile.belongsTo(user)`  examples here: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/#foreign-keys_1 .  Also move `postgres.sync` to the end of file.

Comment: that worked. I have another question. can you help me with it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021524/adding-two-of-the-same-foreighn-keys-to-a-single-model-as-two-different-fields-i @num8er